# The following activities do not have linked reasons: Activity: A@/pvob

Tags: clearcase-ucm

When I try to deliver from clearprojexp I receive following message:

> The following activities do not have linked reasons: Activity: A@/pvob

Can someone tell me what means this error? and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You should only see that kind of message if there is an integration between ClearCase and another application which requires that UCM activities are linked to a "reason" (whatever that is)

The usual link that can be found is a ClearCase-ClearQuest integration.
You have also a connector between ClearCase and RTC (Rational Team Concert)

Any kind of bridge between ClearCase and a third-party software might explain that kind of error message that, otherwise, you shouldn't see when doing a deliver between to UCM stream with the ClearCase Project Explorer (`clearprojexp`).